# Are EJB method parameters validated automatically in a Java EE container?

Tags: jakarta-ee, ejb, bean-validation

I'm new to Java Bean Validation so I'm trying to understand how it works.
From what I know, in a Java EE container, with JPA the persistence provider takes care of the validation of the entities so that there's no need to do it programmatically with a `Validator`.
Are also EJB method parameters validated automatically?
If I have a `@Local` interface, implemented by an EJB:

```java
@Local
public interface ExampleLocal
{
    void doSomething(@NotNull String param);
}
```

And I pass `null` to the above method:

```java
public class Foo 
{
    @EJB
    private ExampleLocal example;

    public void callDoSomething()
    {
        example.doSomething(null);
    }
}
```

Does the EJB throw an `EJBException`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that EJB method parameters are not validated automatically.
I tested in TomEE and I had to use an **Interceptor** to validate them

```java
@Interceptor
@Validable
public class ValidationInterceptor
{
    @Resource
    private Validator validator;
    
    @AroundInvoke
    private Object validate(InvocationContext ic) throws Exception
    {
        ExecutableValidator exVal = validator.forExecutables();
        Set<ConstraintViolation<Object>> violations =  exVal.validateParameters(ic.getTarget(),ic.getMethod(),ic.getParameters());
        if (!violations.isEmpty())
            throw new ConstraintViolationException(violations);
        return ic.proceed();
    }
}
```